# Of course the PHP will not fire under the javascript. But what alternative do I have?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a div whose properties I would like to change dynamically.
Therefore, I am using jquery.keyframes (plugin).

The class second has a low-res blurred background image from **croploads** directory. Now I want to change the image to the high-res version using keyframes from the **croploads2** directory.

The code looks like this:

```
<div class="second" style="width:600px; height:auto; background-image:url(croploads/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<img src="croploads2/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>" style="max-width:100%; visibility:hidden;">
</div>

<script>
$(window).load(function() {
                #preloading the high-res image from croploads2
                $.keyframe.define([{
                      

                      name: 'preload',
                      '0%': {background:'url(croploads2/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>)'}}, {
                      name: 'sharpen',
                      '0%': {background:'url(croploads/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>)', filter: 'blur(100px)'},
                     '80%': {background:'url(croploads/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>)', 'background-size':'contain', filter: 'blur(80px)', opacity: '1'},
                    '100%': {background:'url(croploads2/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>)', 'background-size':'contain', filter: 'blur(0px)', opacity: '1'}
                    }]);
                  });
</script>
```

How can I use php or a javascript variable to accomplish this?
How can I get the blurring effect of images?

Or alternatively, it would be nice to understand how to create lazy-loading of images with php?

Comment: Are you loading both resolution on initial document load??

Comment: @JensonMJohn What I am doing is - setting the dimensions of div (class second) to the dimensions of the high-res version, but setting the background image as the low-res version. And later in the script, I am preloading the high-res version on document load.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see so much wrong with your code. However, so long as your PHP File is the same as the File where you put your JS; You could try something like this:

```
(function($) {
    /** jQuery Document Ready */
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $.keyframe.define([{
        //preloading the high-res image from croploads2
                  name: 'preload',
                  '0%': {background:'url(croploads2/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>)'}  
                }, {
                  name: 'sharpen',
                  '0%': {background:'url(croploads/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>)', filter: 'blur(100px)'},
                 '80%': {background:'url(croploads/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>)', 'background-size':'contain', filter: 'blur(80px)', opacity: '1'},
                '100%': {background:'url(croploads2/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>)', 'background-size':'contain', filter: 'blur(0px)', opacity: '1'}
                }]);
              });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

By the way; make sure that $row['file'] exist at the specified location. The File Pointer "croploads/jpeg.jpg" seem fairly more like a relative URL. Can you access relative URL like that? If not, why not try the fully qualified resource address like "http://example.com/croploads/jpeg.jpg" 
I think this could do the trick.